# Intrinsic way of reviewing my unaccepted questions in each SE site

Tags: feature-request, support

I find it really unusual that (at least as far as I've seen) there is no built in mechanism for viewing questions that *I've* asked that I have not accepted an answer for. Based on my searches, there is a way to query this manually via search:

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

However, this is fairly unintuitive since I seem to have difficulty memorizing this and am constantly having to Google for how to do this.

Is there no built in mechanism to do this in the UI? And if not, could one be added?

Comment: Create a bookmark?

Comment: @DavidPostill A bookmark for each SE site? That would be unwieldy. A simple button on my profile or on the UI *somewhere* would be much better.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I've seen that one already. I'm not asking how to do it as much as I'm inquiring on ui elements. And partly this is a feature request.

Comment: At least it is only one bookmark :/

Comment: @void.pointer: To generalize this question it would mean that you need to provide a button for each possible search, which won't happen. There are only a view buttons which provide specific search options and that's that. In my opinion, the current search option (intuitive or not) is meant to provide this general capability.